# Displaying text file content using jquery in Rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to load the contents of a text file using jquery `$.get` / `$.load` functions but I am getting errors due to routing rules.

My code is as follows:

```
$.get(
    '/root/test.txt',
    function(data) {        
        $('#textfile').html("");
        lines = data.split("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {    
            $('#textfile').append("<div class='row-fluid'>");   
            $('#textfile').append(lines[i]);
            $('#textfile').append("</div>");    
        }
    }
);
```

I am getting this error:

> Started GET "/root/test.txt" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-18 14:36:30 +0700
>   Processing by ErrorsController#routing as TEXT
>   Parameters: {"a"=>"root/test"}
>   Rendered public/404.html.erb within layouts/responsive (0.6ms)

Any suggestions to get this working?

Comment: put test.txt in your public directory and call it from there. If you want this to be symlinked when you deploy it, put it in /public/system

Answer (score 0):

you cant load any file like this..... this will call get method , which will be ajax call... so if you want to load text that is placed in your root directory.. simply use $.load() to load that file...!!

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, I assume you already have MVC architecture going on. Make a controller (or function inside that controller) and send GET request to that controller to return text file content.

So you would want to do

Jquery AJAX request

```
$.get("/readText", function(data){
    console.log(data);   //text file content
});
```

And from your controller (Rails), use IO API provided by rails framework and read your text file and print out the contents of file as you normally do it with other view files. `data` parameter from jquery ajax is going to contain text file contents

---

Or you can straightly map to location of your text file like

```
$.get("resources/test.txt", function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

---

You have mentioned that you are getting 404 error. This means it couldn't locate the text file (or controller of your MVC app) according to the URL path specified by you. Quick and efficient way to examine if you can reach your public resource is just through typing in URL on your web browser (e.g. localhost:8080/yourapp/resources/test.txt). However, I think reading resources from server then printing out is more secure than just accessing publicly.

Comment: you can also use .load but i prefer get request because the syntax is simpler and easy to use. Moreover, purpose of using them are roughly similar. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I've tried that. I could see the contents of the file on the console but in javascript when i try alert(data), i am getting "undefined"

Comment: Are you printing out anything to the requesting page when you are sending $.get request to your rails app? In PHP sense, I read file then go echo fileData;